# How can I create user from another user on hp vertica?

Tags: database, vertica

I want to create user from another user on hp vertica.

How can I create user from another user with data?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a "user provisioning" question. There's no command `CREATE USER x LIKE y...` but you can easily automate this process using roles and a script going through the following steps:

```
CREATE USER newuser IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd' ... ;
GRANT myrole TO newuser ;     
ALTER USER newuser DEFAULT ROLE myrole ... ;
```

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar No one understands what you mean by "same data"

Comment: can you delete your answer, (i want to delete this question it is not helpful)

Answer (score 1):

See below procedure assumes you want to replicate dbadmin user into dbadmin_tmp (data will be share between both users , in vertica data manage by schema's )

```
SELECT 'CREATE USER '||user_name||'_tmp ACCOUNT '||CASE
                                                       WHEN is_locked=FALSE THEN 'UNLOCK'
                                                       ELSE 'LOCK'
                                                   END ||' IDENTIFIED BY ''password'' MEMORYCAP '||
                                                   CASE
                                                       WHEN memory_cap_kb='unlimited' THEN 'NONE'
                                                       ELSE ''||memory_cap_kb||''
                                                   END ||' PROFILE '||profile_name||' RESOURCE POOL  '||resource_pool||' RUNTIMECAP '|| 
                                                   CASE 
                                                       WHEN run_time_cap='unlimited' THEN 'NONE'
                                                       ELSE ''||run_time_cap||''
                                                   END ||' TEMPSPACECAP '||CASE
WHEN temp_space_cap_kb='unlimited' THEN 'NONE'
ELSE ''||temp_space_cap_kb||''
END ||CASE
          WHEN search_path ILIKE '' THEN ''
          ELSE ' SEARCH_PATH '||search_path
      END
FROM users
WHERE user_name='dbadmin'
```

Comment: can you delete your answer, (i want to delete this question it is not helpful)